# Ionic app: Google maps + uiGmapgoogle-maps

Tags: ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, meta-tags, content-security-policy

a few years ago I have implemented in an iconic app the use of google maps, with uiGmapgoogle-maps component.

Currently, it is still working, but it does not show any images, the “icons” of google maps.

The error it shows is:

```
Content Security Policy: Las opciones para esta página han bloqueado la carga de un recurso en data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22h… (default-src).
```

OR

```
Refused to load the image 'data:image/svg+xml,...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

With this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

What should I do to keep seeing the content well?
Thanks

Comment: Add `img-src * data:;` to the policy

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker works!

Answer (score 0):

Add img-src * data:; to the policy works!